# How to debug memory management in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

It is well [established](http://whentouseretaincount.com) that `-retainCount` is useless, even--or rather *in particular*(?)--for debugging purposes.

So, pretending we are in a world without ARC, what strategies are out there to debug memory related issues? How can I verify that an object is deleted when I think it is?

I'm asking because, as a learner of objective-c, I would like to verify when resources get deallocated in some not-so-obvoius situations (for example when transfers of ownership take place during bridged casts).

Comment: Call `NSLog()` in `-dealloc`. Make it shout out the pointer and the class of the object that is being deallocated. And/or place a breakpoint in `dealloc`.

Comment: Is `-dealloc` called in a similar fashion to a c++ destructor?

Comment: Yes. [15 characters]

Comment: yes it it works like c++ destrutior. Only difference is that without ARC you have to call manually `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: try also memory detection tool (it works very well). Choose `Product/Profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the day when I wanted to verify that I wasn't leaking a particular kind of object I'd do something like the following:

```
static int gAllocCount = 0;

@implementation MyClass 

- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"ALLOC MyClass %d", ++gAllocCount);
    return [super init];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"DEALLOC MyClass %d", --gAllocCount);
}
```

These days, I use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Some tasks in Instruments aren't as easy as perhaps they ought to be, but it's a very powerful tool once you know how to use it.  You can log every alloc/retain/release/dealloc of every object, complete with stack traces, and you can filter by specific class names.